# Laravel homestead per project installation (vagrant up error)

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have created a Laravel project with an Homestead per project installation. After that I have pushed it on a git repository, https://github.com/FELPONE/Laravel-Rate-Limit.git.

Now I am trying to initialize the same project on another machine. I have cloned the project from the repo but when I start vagrant up,I receive error:

There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded
and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by
a syntax error.

```
Path: /home/yourname/Desktop/rate-limit/Vagrantfile
Line number: 0
Message: LoadError: cannot load such file -- /home/yourname/Desktop/rate-limit/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb
```

Which are the correct steps to set up it correctly?

Answer (score -1):

You need to run the `make` command.

```
php vendor/bin/homestead make
```

More info here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead#per-project-installation